# Can any one explain this xpath

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Anyone can you please explain this xpath please.
why we use '"+filterBy+"' rather than "+filterBy +" in this code segment.
(I just simplify the code.this not an original one.)

```
String filterBy = "Hio";
System.out.println("//div[@class='filter-option-control-music']/div/label/span[text()='"+ filterBy + "']");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's split the elements of  your string. You have a string, plus a variable, plus another string:

- string1:`//div[@class='filter-option-control-music']/div/label/span[text()='`
- variable: `filterBy`, with value Hio, as string
- string2:`']`

In programming, strings are stored between double quotes usually, so string1 and string1 become:

- `string1 = "//div[@class='filter-option-control-music']/div/label/span[text()='"`
- `string2 = "']"`

So, `string1 + string2 = "//div[@class='filter-option-control-music']/div/label/span[text()='']"`

Now, if we want to also add the `filterBy` variable, we have:

string1 + variable + string2:`"//div[@class='filter-option-control-music']/div/label/span[text()='" + filterBy + "']"`,

therefore, our new string will be:

```
"//div[@class='filter-option-control-music']/div/label/span[text()='Hio']"
```

We use `'"+filterBy+"'` rather than `"+filterBy +"`, because ' and ' quotes are from `text()=' '`.

If we would use `"+filterBy +"` we would have this string:

```
"//div[@class='filter-option-control-music']/div/label/span[text()=Hio]"
```

which is an incorrect xpath, because strings are always between double or single quotes.

More information on strings manipulation can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings

Comment: this one is more appreciated and expected.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not

> '"+filterBy+"' rather than "+filterBy +"

It's different types of quotation marks used to build a string with quotations inside it. The result is

```
//div[@class='filter-option-control-music']/div/label/span[text()='Hio']
```

Two '-s around Hio are the `'"` and `"'`.

Here you can read a bit more - [Using quotation marks inside quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050355/python-using-quotation-marks-inside-quotation-marks).